# Returning an object from a subroutine

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a routine that returns mostly correct data. I pass it a string Id code, it creates a model, gets data from a database, fills in the model, and then passes the model back. The return model looks correct and has correct data except the List's in the model do not contain any data.

The model looks similar to this one

```
             public class SubjectDB
             {
                public string SubjectId  { get; set; }
                .
                .
                List<AddressDB> Address { get; set; }
                .
                .
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
             }
             public class DBEntities: DbContent
             {
                public DbSet<SubjectDB> SubjectDB { get; set; }
                public DbSet<AddressDB> AddressDB { get; set; }
                .
                .
             }
```

The subroutine is called using this code

```
             SubjectDB xsubject = new SubjectDB();
             xsubject = (SubjectDB)GetNewSubject(model.Subject.Id);
```

The subroutine is

```
             Public object GetNewSubject( string Id )
             {

                 SubjectDB subjectdb = new SubjectDB();
                 DBEntites db = new DBEntities();

                 var subjectxx = db.SubjectDB.First(x => x.SubjectId == Id);
                 var addressxx = db.AddressDB.First(x => x.SubjectId == Id);
                 .
                 .
                 subjectdb.SubjectId = subjectxx.Subjectid;
                 .
                 .
                 List<AddressDB> Address = new List<AddressDB>();
                 Address.Add(addressxx);
                 .
                 .
                 return(subjectdb);
              }
```

I can mouse over the subjectdb in the subroutine and see all the data including the data in the List's, but when I mouse over the returned object "xsubject", I see all the correct returned data but the List's are empty.

Comment: Public `SubjectDB` GetNewSubject( string Id )? Why not return the correct type instead of casting everytime? The `First()` statements will throw an exception when you try to find a subject id that doesn't exist in your database. (you can use `FirstOrDefault` and get null when the id is not present)

Comment: Please do not return `object` from methods unless there is very good reason to do so (not in your case as you immediately cast result back to its type). Also in C# methods are usually called just methods, it "routine"/"subroutine" is significantly less common.

Comment: I think we need more information about the database structure and the rest of the code to really tell you much. I would suggest using the proper types and try again, but I have doubts that will do much.

Comment: I started back when FORTRAN and COBALT were programming KINGS. Long before K&R even thought of "C". So Main, Routine, and Subroutines are burned into this old brain.

Comment: Thanks for the FirstorDefault. I forgot about if a Null is returned.

Comment: As you can see the LIST are part of the model that is being used and I am filling the LIST with data. So what do I do to make it pass the LIST back? The non-LIST code pass correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the missing piece of the puzzel. I was not initializing the Lists even if they are public.

Model modified to:

```
              public class SubjectDB   
     {   
        public string SubjectId  { get; set; }   
        .   
        .   
        public List<AddressDB> Address { get; set; }   
        .   
        .   
        [Key]   
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public SubjectDB()
        {
           this.Address = new List<AddressDB>();
           .
           .
        }   
     }   
     public class DBEntities: DbContent   
     {   
        public DbSet<SubjectDB> SubjectDB { get; set; }   
        public DbSet<AddressDB> AddressDB { get; set; }   
        .   
        .   
     }
```

Now it all works. the DbSet commands get the data from the database and the LIST get updated correctly and when the model is passed back to the main, all the data is there.

Thanks to all that helped me see where I had gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing this line in `GetNewSubject`?

```
subjectdb.Address = Address;
```

**Update:**

Also, your `Address` property of your `SubjectDB` class needs to be public:

```
public List<AddressDB> Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: Look carefully and you will see that I get the Address data from the Database and insert it directly into the LIST, that is part of the mdoel "subjectdb".

Comment: @JohnDonaldson -- I'm not sure what you mean. You are creating a List of AddressDB objects, but that List is not the same as the List of the subjectdb object until you set them equal to each other, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 1):

Address is a newly created object in the function (subroutine is so Basic with line numbers :-) ). You're not adding it to the subjectdb in any way, so it's just a local variable. You need to actually return it, or store it somewhere that the called can access it.

Comment: So how do I add it. I am filling in LIST that are part of the model, that is being passed back to the main routine. The LIST show up when I look in main but contain none of the data I put in them.

Answer (score 0):

Further testing shows that the data is really not getting into the Model List. It is getting into the local LIST but not the Model's LIST. So how do I move the Data into the Model LIST varible and not a local LIST varible. In my case the model contains

```
           public clsss SubjectDB
           {
             public string SubjectId { get; set;}
             .
             .
             LIST<AddressDB> Address { get; set; }
```

So how do I access the LIST in the model. I can access the string, int, DateTime, bool data just fine. But how to I access the LIST to add data to it?

Answer (score 0):

Late yesterday, I discovered what some of you now pointed out. I did not make the LIST public, so is not seen. I have now fixed that problem but now run into a different problem.

Model

```
          public class SubjectDB  
         {  
            public string SubjectId  { get; set; }  
            .  
            .  
            public List<AddressDB> Address { get; set; }  
            .  
            .  
            [Key]  
            public int Id { get; set; }  
         }  
         public class DBEntities: DbContent  
         {  
            public DbSet<SubjectDB> SubjectDB { get; set; }  
            public DbSet<AddressDB> AddressDB { get; set; }  
            .  
            .  
         }
```

Now when the database query executes, I get back the correct data

```
          Public object GetNewSubject( string Id )     
         {     

             SubjectDB subjectdb = new SubjectDB();     
             DBEntites db = new DBEntities();     

             var subjectxx = db.SubjectDB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubjectId == Id);     
             var addressxx = db.AddressDB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubjectId == Id);     
             .     
             .     
             subjectdb.SubjectId = subjectxx.Subjectid;
             subjectdb.Name = subjectxx.Name;     
             .     
             .
             // Put LIST data into LIST          
             subjectdb.Address.Add(addressxx);     
             .     
             .     
             return(subjectdb);     
          }
```

It now errors at the "subjectdb.Address.Add(addressxx);" statement. I get a "NullReferenceException", object referenced not set to an instance of a object?